# Как перевести каретку на новую строку json?

Tags: php, json

Приветствую!
По событию выполняется функция:

```
$file = file_get_contents('ajax/data.json'); 
$myArr = json_decode($file,TRUE); 
unset($file);  
$arr = array("type" => "Feature","id" => $id);                  
if (!empty($taskList["features"])) {
$i=0;
foreach ( $myArr["features"]  as $key => $value) {      
  if (in_array( $id, $value)) {    
    $myArr["features"][$key] = $arr;
    $i++;
  };
};
   if ($i == 0) {
    $myArr["features"][] = $arr;
   };
} else {
  $myArr["features"][] = $arr; 
};  
$json = json_encode($myArr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | 
JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
file_put_contents('ajax/data.json', $json);
unset($myArr);
```

Все работает на выходе получаю файл json с кодом:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features":[{"type":"Feature","id":0},
{"type":"Feature","id":1},{"type":"Feature","id":2}]}
```

Хотелось бы получить строку в таком виде:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", 
   "features":[
      {"type":"Feature","id":0},
      {"type":"Feature","id":1},
      {"type":"Feature","id":2}
   ]}
```

Comment: Но зачем?......

Comment: \r\n в двойных кавычках не работает?

Comment: Нужно иногда "ручками править".

Comment: \r\n не работает

Comment: Присоеденяюсь к @AGS17 зачем? есил нужно что то читабельное возьмите csv.

Comment: Для вывода json в человекочитаемом виде есть флаг JSON_PRETTY_PRINT. Странно, что вы его не заметили, но нашли рядом его ровесников JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE и JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES

Comment: Спасибо. флаг помог!!!

Comment: учтите только, что не все средства просмотра вам позволят открыть json-файл с переносами строк, это не валидно